# Which user-defined-literals are predefined by the standard?

Tags: c++, c++11, user-defined-literals

My question sounds like a contradiction, but I don't know how else to refer to the new literal syntax other than `user-defined-literal`.

```
std::string operator "" s ( const char* str, size_t len )
{
   return std::string( str, len );
}

assert( "foo"s == "bar"s );
```

I remember hearing that user defined literals should start with an `_` prefix.  That would imply that the library defines some non-prefixed literals for us.

Does the standard provide some UDLs in the the standard library?
If yes, what are they?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The language already use regular literals suffixes, for example `1U`.

It would become ambiguous if you were to use `U` as a user-defined-literal, thus the recommendation.

*integer-suffix*: `u`, `U`, `l`, `L`, `ll`, `LL`

*floating-suffix*: `f`, `F`, `l`, `L`

Answer (score 6):

The standard library actually defines **no** user defined literals. We would perhaps have expected complex numbers, but no.

On the other hand, there is also a proposal to remove them again

http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2011/n3250.html

so we don't yet know what happens.

Comment: Given that the proposal was trying to remove them from C11 and push them to a _later_ iteration of the standard, and that C11 has now been published _with_ them, we can probably ignore said proposal :-)

Answer (score 2):

In contrast to @Matthieu's answer, the [FIDS](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2011/n3290.pdf) says the following under 2.14.8 [lex.ext] p1:

> If a token matches both *user-defined-literal* and another literal kind, it is treated as the latter.
> [ *Example:*
> **123_km** is a *user-defined-literal*, but **12LL** is an *integer-literal*. — *end example* ]

So even if you define those literals, the predefined ones are taken and there is no ambiguity.

Answer (score 1):

No standard library components have staked a claim on a user-defined literal.  @Bo mentioned complex as a possibility.

Another is bitset:

```
template<char... Bits>
  inline constexpr std::bitset<sizeof...(Bits)>
  operator"" bits()
  {
    return std::bitset<sizeof...(Bits)>((char []){Bits..., '\0'});
  }
```

I predict there will be proposals for literal operators for various library components in the upcoming library TR2 enhancements.

I anticipate some collisions over the suffix namespace.  You can declare literal operators in a namespace and prevent multiple ambiguous definitions but you can't distinguish the actual suffixes by namespace in an actual literal.  We'll see.

Comment: Note that the standard explicitly reserves _all_ literal suffixes that don't start with an underscore for future standardization.