# Where is the standard library predefined 'user-defined' literal "m" defined?

Tags: c++, std, units-of-measurement

I stumbled upon the following example while browsing the [C++ Core Guidlines](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#example-2) document:

> **Example**
>
> ```
> change_speed(double s);   // bad: what does s signify?
> // ...
> change_speed(2.3);
> ```
>
> A better approach is to be explicit about the meaning of the double (new speed or delta on old speed?) and the unit used:
>
> ```
> change_speed(Speed s);    // better: the meaning of s is specified
> // ...
> change_speed(2.3);        // error: no unit
> change_speed(23m / 10s);  // meters per second
> ```
>
> We could have accepted a plain (unit-less) double as a delta, but that would have been error-prone.

With regard to that last line of code, there was no mention on that specific page what that syntax meant, and it looked positively alien to me.

After several hours <s>wasted</s> invested figuring out this is probably a standard library predefined 'user-defined' literal and learning more about them, I tried to find out where this particular literal is defined, but while 's' is mentioned [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/user_literal#Standard_library) along with a handful of other literals, I found no information on 'm'.

There is also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5380358/4183191) question on SO, but I think the answers there seem to be completely out of date.

**Q: Where is the standard-library predefined user-defined literal "m" defined*?**

---

<sub>* Sweet, sweet alliteration.</sub>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**It is not a standard user defined literal**

The list of standard user defined literals can be found here at the bottom: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/user_literal

And `operator""m` is not one of them, as the standard library does not deal with units of length (yet).

Comment: Thanks Fatih. I've actually already linked to that link in the question :)  So if `23m` is not a standard library literal, what is this? Or if it _is_ a user-defined literal but just not a standard library one, why is it allowed without an underscore?

Comment: Or are you just saying Bjarne probably invented a literal that isn't in the standard library yet, just for the purpose of that example?

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou, well, Bjarne in fact likes to make some functionality up so that some examples are clearer (like using ranges in his C++11/14 book). As you've said, it is not allowed to be used without an underscore. So, until we get standard units of length, that code is ill formed.